# Generic lambda method signature

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

I am sure this is pretty standard stuff, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

I'm writing a simple helper class for executing code in separate threads. I'm very familiar with how to do this in general, but not using lambdas. I guess this is about general lambda usage, rather than threads.

What I want to be able to write is something like this:

```
ThreadedMethods.Parameterized<int>((i) => { for (;i < 10; i++;) DoSomething();});
```

and

```
ThreadedMethods.Parameterized<IEnumberable<Something>>((list) => 
{
    foreach (var s in list)
    {
         s.SomeHeavyProcessing();
    }
});
```

Is this possible? And, moreover, is there any reason to try to achieve this in the first place, since the lambda will have access to everything within the scope of the method call?

Comment: Why not just use TPL or PLinq or something already written that will parallelize tasks?  No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: FWIW, Links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx (Task Parallel Library), and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx (Parallel LINQ). TPL has methods for exactly what you're doing, but don't get me wrong, I've done exactly what you've done before they were available in .NET 4.

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted to do was to wrap a simple Thread.Start(ParameterizedThreadStart) into a single method with an Action<T> parameter. But since ParameterizedThreadStart doesn't (!) have a generic sister, the code wouldn't compile. TPL's Task<T> doesn't really do what I want. But my question remains; Is there any reason for me to actually want that, since the lambda code will have access to all scoped variables anyway?

Comment: It is not clear as to what your hesitation about the lambda code having access to all scoped variables is. Keep in mind that the lambda code doesn't automatically have access to all the scoped variables while it is being executed - instead you can use local scoped variables in a lambda, which will result in creation of a closure for that variable. So, in plain terms, only the variables that are used in the lambda code will be accessible at the time of execution of that code. Wikipedia on closures: http://goo.gl/aNd5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. You should have implementation for

```
class ThreadedMethods {
    public static void Parameterized<T>(Action<T> action) {
        // Start the action on a different thread using possibly ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
    }
}
```

Then you call your implementation as you have shown with your examples in your question.

**EDIT: More info on how you can call the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method when you have Action**

```
    public void StartOnDifferentThread<T>(Action<T> action, T input)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => action((T)o), input);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the spirit of his question, which is more about closures, lambdas, and stack frames than it is about generics.

Comment: Reading the question again doesn't still give me that clarity though. What the OP wanted, IMO is to know how to construct a generic method that can accept a lambda and how he can then run that lambda on a different thread and I think my answer helps him achieve that.

Comment: Yeah, my post was a bit unclear. I am familiar with how to specify Action<T>, but what I failed to achieve was to actually instantiate a ParameterizedThreadStart with an Action<T>, it only works for Action<object>, since that's what ParameterizedThreadStart accepts. I was a bit vague on purpose, though, since I wanted to hear of alternative aproaches and general use of lambdas. +1 for the answer, though, because it isn't wrong. :)